# Access - Open different report from one button

Tags: ms-access, vba

How I can open diferents reports from one button in access if that form that shows me the information has been filtred. For example, in one form I have 2 elements, "t_element"=3 means is ID and name of report is "DNI_CAB", when "t_element"=54 means is Table and name of report is "Table_CAB". And if I filtred another form maybe shows me 8 elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this properly, you need to make this table-driven.  By that, I mean you need to set up a table with 2 fields; ID and Report  Call it tblReports.

Then you would do something like this on the OnClick event of the button:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim MyReport as String

Set db = CurrentDB
'Find the Report you're going to use by filtering by the ID you want
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select Report from tblReports where ID = " & me.txtID & "")

'Fill a variable with the resulting value
MyReport = rec(0)

'Now that we have the report name, open it
DoCmd.OpenReport MyReport
```

This is all entirely aircode, written off the top of my head, so it probably needs to be altered a little.  But it should give you an idea of how to go about writing the code to get this done.